# Streaming Image files using Wcf

Tags: wcf, streaming, wcf-client

I want to send a large image to server through Wcf.I may pass it as a byte[].How can i do that.What is MTOM...where can i find a sample...?

Answer (score 5):

MTOM is just an optimized message encoding format. It stands for Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism and transmits as bytes instead of angle brackets (aka XML). [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/632101/Mtom-Encoding-in-WCF) is a basic introduction to using MTOM with WCF.

[This small sample](http://blog.joachim.at/?p=33) should get you started if you want to use streaming, which is a nice option if you want to transmit large files.

Comment: first link (mssolutionhelper) is broken.

Comment: Thanks, replaced with another one.